# Вывод одной даты с одного дня один раз

Tags: дата, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Мне надо вывести дату из бд, находится она в таком формате **00.00.0000 00:00:00** (d.m.Y H:i:s), сделал я вот такой вывод:

`$days = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM refstat WHERE idUser='$_GET[id]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7");`

Здесь я вывожу последние 7 дат, которые есть в бд, они вот такие:

```
04.01.2015 18:48:20 - 1 
03.01.2015 22:44:13 - 2
03.01.2015 22:44:03 - 3
29.12.2014 14:03:18 - 4
29.12.2014 05:24:44 - 5
29.12.2014 04:38:42 - 6
29.12.2014 04:38:30 - 7
```

А мне надо, чтобы выводил по числу (первые 2 цифры) и чтобы их также было 7, но они не повторялись.

Comment:  1. [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru/), как любит повторять @Etki;
 2. Вот с такой дырой: `idUser='$_GET[id]'` вас сломают раньше, чем вы думаете.

Comment: @Sergiks Я знаю, надо сделать экранизацию. htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
Это я не сделал пока что, потому что тестирую просто, после тестирования поставлю. Вы бы лучше ответили на вопрос, а не дыры изучали.

Comment: @cnofss, экранирование, а не экранизацию =)))

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо. Работает. В овет запишите

Comment: По вашему примеру что должно быть в ответе ? 
04
03
03
29
29
29
29 
или
04
03
29
 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выделять дату из этого кривого формата с помощью `STR_TO_DATE()` и группировать по дню: [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5d406/7)